# how to hide console.logs of aggrid?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I haven't passed {debug: true} or anything to gridOptions, yet I am getting tons of logs in console. How can I hide them? Thanks
[image]

Comment: I've not seen logs like that coming from ag-grid.  Can you recreate it in StackBlitz or similar?